# Shipping Information carrier title

Tags: shipping

[image]

how can i add a default title automatically. I have just one carrier in the list.

```
public function getCarriers()    {

    $carriers = parent::getCarriers();

    $carriers['Swiss_Post'] = $this->__('Swiss Post');
    return $carriers;
}
```

}